# Issues with zip file upload in php/magento

Tags: php, file, magento, zip, unzip

This is the code I am trying to upload a zip and extract zip at  a location-

```
//Path where extracted files to be stored, path is correct already checked
$path = Mage::getBaseDir(). DS .'pdf_locator'. DS;

$zip = new ZipArchive;
echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);
echo $_FILES['filename']['name'];

$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$res = $zip->open("$name");//File name in server.
echo " --- ", $res, " --- ";
die;
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($path);//Destination directory
    $zip->close();
    echo 'successfully extracted';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Output --

```
Array
(
    [filename] => Array
        (
            [name] => swap.zip
            [type] => application/zip
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpqx2qH2
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 478441
        )

)
swap.zip --- 11 ---
```

I was expecting `TRUE` but it is throwing error code `11` [from the docs]. Let me know what I am doing wrong with the code.

FYI - Zip is enabled, please check screenshot.

[image: zipinfo]

Comment: Are you running under Windows by chance? If so, try `move_uploaded_file()` before opening the zip.

Comment: @JürgenThelen nah its PHP Version 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.10

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take the 'tmp_name' of the file located on the server to open the archive?

```
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
```

Should look like this?

```
$name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
```

If I am wrong: did you check the file system permissions (r/w/x)?

Comment: I've found a list with the error codes: [link](http://shashikantbhosale.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/list-of-error-codes-returns-during-use-of-php-zip-functions/), maybe this helps?

Comment: ahh ..nice info ..any guess whr to dig more ??

Comment: You know what, I think the echo is trolling you now :P Remove the "die;" and look if your "===" check for TRUE will pass, I think the echo just displays the TRUE as a "1" - and ask for the error codes only, if it's not true:

echo 'failed, error code: '.$res;

Comment: aah no luck..let me kow if u came across some solution

Comment: Hm sorry that it didn't work out, but I searched a little bit and found an article doing what you are trying to achieve, it's almost the same just that he moves the file first - maybe it works for you: [link](http://bavotasan.com/2010/how-to-upload-zip-file-using-php/)

Comment: Alright I copied your script and tested it at my local host, got the error code 11 in the beginning (because you didn't use the "tmp_name"), changed that, then I received the code "1" -> removed your "die;" instruction - the "1" wasn't an error code, it was the TRUE - please try it again, maybe you have an issue with the provided $path and it doesn't extract it to the expected location - but you should get a success message that it enters the block (do an echo inside the if($res === TRUE)) - good luck! ;)